# How to log exceptions in asp.net core app using ApplicationInsights 2.x when DeveloperExceptionPage is used

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

Is there any documentation regarding ApplicationInsights 2.x and asp.net core?

I've found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-exceptions, but is looks obsolete.

It uses 'HandleErrorAttribute', but it is .NET Framework's class, not .net core.

Answer (score 5):

In ASP.NET Core, you could handle exception by implementing IExceptionFilter interface. Code below is for your reference.

```
public class GlobalExceptionFilter : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
        var properties = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "custom-property1", "property1-value" } };
        telemetry.TrackException(context.Exception, properties);
    }
}
```

After define the filter, you could register it when adding MVC service in ConfigureServices method.

```
services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(opt=> { opt.Filters.Add(new GlobalExceptionFilter()); });
```

Comment: Any update? If my reply help you fix your issue, please mark it as answer. Otherwise, please provide more information for further discussion.